# how to pass variables to event listener method in d3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm working with **d3**, **svg** and **AngularJS**.

I've written some code to handle `mouseup` event on an svg element using d3. The code is as follows:

```
<svg>
    <!-- some other code-->
</svg>

function myFunction() {
    var isMouseUp = false;
    d3.select("svg").on("mouseup", func1);
}

function func1() {
    isMouseUp = true;
}
```

As you can see, `isMouseUp` is a local variable to `myFunction()`.
I have to pass it to `func1()`. How can I do so?

P.S. I can't make `isMouseUp` global. Also I can't make `func1()` local to `myFunction()`.

Comment: You have to declare `isMouseUp outside of any function for it to be accessible in `func1()`. You don't need to send it through the function call, in your example.

Comment: @RoySchoep Thanks for reply but if I take the variable outside of function, it will become global & I can't do that because of some historical reasons. Is there some way out so that I can pass the variable while calling `func1()`?

Comment: That is probably possible, but that won't solve anything in your example. You can't change the value of isMouseUp in `func1()` because it is in the scope of `myFunction()` if you have to manipulate a variable within multiple functions you definitely going to need a global variable.

Comment: @RoySchoep Yes I faced the issue you've talked about. In that case what I did is I have taken a JSON object and in that I've taken the variable. I didn't mention it for the sake of simplicity of the question.

Comment: You can make a inline function of func1 `d3.select("svg").on("mouseup", function(isMouseUp){  func1(isMouseUp);} );` func1() should look like `function func1(isMouseUp){}`

Comment: @RoySchoep I know that but as I've mentioned in the last line, I can't make `func1` a local function. Firstly because it's called from some other code also and secondly `func1` is a big function which in turn will make `myFunction()` bigger, which obviously is not good.

Comment: Okay.. so you need to make the variable `isMouseUp` available to `func1()` but without executing the function? How can the `func1()` not be a local function? Is it part of a class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45467/discussion-between-ras-and-roy-schoep)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the call to `func1` in another function:

```
function myFunction() {
   var isMouseUp = false;
   d3.select("svg").on("mouseup", function() { func1(isMouseUp); });
}

function func1(isMouseUp) {
   isMouseUp = true;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/22jx6/).